# Не присваивается значение переменной при вызове метода C#

Tags: c#, методы, переменные

```
private void HandleCanonFiring()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Instantiate(canonBall, canonSpawnLocation.position, Quaternion.identity);
        BulletLogic action = canonBall.GetComponent<BulletLogic>();
        
        if (action != null)
        {
            action.SendBall(canonSpawnLocation.up, canonForce);//здесь передаю сторону и силу
            print(canonBall);
        }
    }
}
```

код обьекта куда передаю значение

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;


void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}


public void SendBall(Vector2 direction, float force)//а здесь должно быть но нету
{
    if (rb == null)
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    rb.AddForce(direction * force);
    
    print(direction * force);
}
```

Comment: попробуйте сделать переменную статичной

Comment: я просто в самом коде объекта добавил силу в апдейте в зависимости от его поворота, получилось немного не то что я задумывал но зато свою задачу выполняет